# Why does my Printwriter not work like i want?

Tags: java, serversocket, printwriter

I have a Problem with my Printwriter in some of my Projects. I always have to close it because otherwise the send message of the Serversockets doesn´t come to the wished server.

```
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

console.writeMessageinConsole("Client"+socket.getInetAddress()+" verbindet!");

OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream, true);

System.out.println("da");

printWriter.write("dadad");

printWriter.close();
```

Can you plase help me?

Comment: Dont forget to `flush()` after writing to make sure data is actually written to the socket i.e do `printWriter.flush()` after calling `write()`

Comment: But autoflush is activated

Comment: ["  autoFlush - A boolean; if true, the println, printf, or format methods will flush the output buffer"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean))  . You're using `write()` use `println()` instead.

Comment: Well, now it partly works.

Comment: The Pc-Part works, but the Server doenst: https://hastebin.com/toxeyiveqe.java

Comment: @MaxiMaxMax you still need to print a new line for auto flush to work.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason to use a BufferedWriter is to buffer the output. If you want to send immediately, don't use buffering.

The only reason to use a PrintWriter is to add println and printf. If you want to use write() you don't need a PrintWriter.

So you can either;

- drop the BufferedWriter.
- use println, or
- flush() the output